# Benefit to use usize intsead of u8 when number will not exceed u8 range?

Tags: rust, types

I was planning on using a tuple struct like `struct Wrap(pub u8)` to represent a number (which never exceeds 63) when it occurred to me that there may be no benefit to using `u8` over `usize` instead, and using `usize` saves me from casting when I need to use the number to index into a slice. `u8` "saves" me 3 bytes, but I'm not certain of that with data alignment on 64-bit processors.

Apart from "use the most appropriate data type", to which I think `u8` and `usize` are equally applicable in my situation, what are the benefits to using `u8` over `usize` and vice versa?

Comment: from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44685633/is-casting-between-integers-expensive), there is no need to worry about speed. Therefore it seems that, regarding your problem, the benefit of using `usize` would be the coding convenience, while the benefit of using `u8` would be the save of storage space (at the cost of coding convenience).

Answer (score 3):

If your number is going to be used as an index, it should be a [`usize`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.usize.html). That's essentially what `usize` means.

[See also this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29592256/whats-the-difference-between-usize-and-u32)

Sure, if you are going to have a bazillion of them, such that saving three bytes each actually matters, you *might* consider casting between `u8` and `usize`. But you should think pretty hard about how much this might actually matter before you introduce this optimization with its extra complexity and potential footguns (or at least toestubs).